# What statistical tests to use when comparing pricing data?

Tags: regression, correlation, model

I'm trying to work out whether absolute, relative price and price proximity to nearest competitor product affect customer gains and which one is more important for a project. I've ran correlations which show relationships of varying degrees but these variables obviously correlate with each other. Would the next step be to do regression or are there other tests I could be looking at. I'm assuming I would have to do separate regressions on each of the variables rather than multiple regression? I do have daily sales data. I'm new to stats so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are the study's questions?

Comment: does absolute and/or relative price matter in the market?
does price proximity to the nearest product matter? When I say matter it means do they impact on customer gains? The product is a subscription service. I'd also like to know if relative price is more important than absolute price. does that make sense?